# Angular - Textarea directive maxHeight

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, textarea, directive

Currently, I am using the following code to write a directive for auto-sizing a text area depending on user input:

```
import { ElementRef, HostListener, Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]'
})

export class Autosize implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  onInput(textArea:HTMLTextAreaElement):void {
    this.adjust();
  }

  constructor(public element:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    setTimeout(() => this.adjust(), 0);
  }

  adjust():void {
    const textArea = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';
    textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

However, I have been struggling to add a maximum height. Since if the user inputs a really long message, the textarea will expand outside the view. Is there a way I can make it expand until rows of textarea reach **3** and then just work like a normal text area with scroll inside and fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add maxHeight to your element style.

[Here's a working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpn6ru)

```
adjust():void {
   const textArea = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
   //textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
   textArea.style.height = 'auto';
   textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
   textArea.style.maxHeight = '100px';
}
```

Comment: I just tried using this, however `maxHeight` does not seem to apply. The textarea still expands more than 100px.

Comment: did you look at the link that I've provided? Could you create one also so I can take a look ?

Comment: Worked out! Thank you!

Comment: great, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a css property max-height for your element.

Comment: I have tried it. However, `maxHeight` does not seem to apply. Textarea is still able to expand more than the given maxHeight.